# Return number field from Parse into Tableview custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, tableview

I have a tableview controller with a custom Prototype Cell.  The cell contains 2 labels.  I am trying to return 2 values from a Parse class.  One field is called Notes and is a String value. The other field is called CreditAmount and is a number value. I am having difficulty returning the number value (Credit Amount) in my tableview.

Here is code for tableview controller:

import UIKit
import Parse
import Foundation

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
var note = [String]()
var credit = [NSInteger]()
```

var refresher: UIRefreshControl!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      self.tableView.reloadData()

    updateNotes()

    self.refresher = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refresher.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    self.refresher.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.tableView.addSubview(refresher)
}


func updateNotes() {

    let query = PFQuery(className: "Paydown")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects:[AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        self.note.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
        self.credit.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

        if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

            for object in objects {

              // var noted = object as PFObject
                self.note.append(object["Notes"] as! String)
                self.credit.append(object["CreditAmount"] as! NSInteger)

            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()


        } else {

            //println(error)
        }

        self.refresher.endRefreshing()

})

}


func refresh() {

    updateNotes()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


return note.count

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell


    myCell.notesLabel.text = note[indexPath.row]
    myCell.amountLabel.text = credit[indexPath.row]

    return myCell

}
```

}

Here is the code for my customer cell:

import UIKit
import Parse

class cell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet weak var notesLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var amountLabel: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

The myCell.amountLabel.text = credit[indexPath.row] causes an error:  cannot assign a value of type NSInteger (aka int) to a  value of type String?.  How do I get the number field to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update

```
myCell.amountLabel.text = credit[indexPath.row]
```

To be

```
myCell.amountLabel.text = "\(credit[indexPath.row])"
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thank you Russell.